# Nawk - nawk out of space in tostring on (compare two files

Tags: unix, awk, nawk

i am running **nawk** scripts on **solaris** system to get records of file1 not in file2 and find duplicate records in a while with the following scripts -

compare:

```
nawk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next;} !a[$0] {print"line":" FNR $0}' file1 file2
```

duplicate:

```
nawk '{a[$0]++}END{for(i in a){if(a[i]-1)print i,a[i]}}' file1
```

in the middle of script i get an error message saying

> nawk: out of space in tostring on record 971360

I am using a file having 2 million records.

Comment: what is your question? Please don't make us guess ;-) If script 1 is working, then use it. Good luck.

Comment: Can the files be sorted? If so then using `comm` for the compare and `uniq` for identifying duplicates would be the normal approach. Post some sample input and expected output if you'd like help.

Answer (score 1):

Correct your code, your double quote is mismatched also..

```
 nawk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next;} !($0 in a){print "line:" FNR $0}' file1 file2
```

**--edit--**

for duplicate try this

```
nawk '{A[$0]++}END{for(i in A)if(A[i]>1)print i,A[i]}' file
```

`!a[0]` --> using `a[$0]` creates an extra empty array element for every `$0` that does not exist in array `a` while reading the second file, so best thing is to do `!($0 in a)`